# list membership test or set

Tags: python, list, set

Is it more efficient to check if an item is already in a list before adding it:

```
for word in open('book.txt','r').read().split():
if word in list:
    pass
else:
    list.append(item)
```

or to add everything then run set() on it? like this:

```
for word in open('book.txt','r').read().split():
    list.append(word)
list = set(list)
```

Comment: Do you want only the unique elements? If No, stop here, else, does the order matter?

Comment: And a `set` shall be constructed like this `listobject = set(listobject)`

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it will shadow the builtin `list` function

Comment: thats not my actual variable, its there for demonstrative purposes

Comment: The first code take O(n^2) time. Just avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the ultimate intention is to construct a set, construct it directly and don't bother with the list:

```
words = set(open('book.txt','r').read().split())
```

This will be simple and efficient.

Just as your original code, this has the downside of first reading the entire file into memory. If that's an issue, this can be solved by reading one line at a time:

```
words = set(word for line in open('book.txt', 'r') for word in line.split())
```

(Thanks @Steve Jessop for the suggestion.)

Definitely don't take the first approach in your question, unless you know the list to be short, as it will need to scan the entire list on every single word.

Comment: I am constructing a list of unique words, sets, as far as I can tell can't store words, `issuperset` would simply tell me if the set contains the letters necessary to construct that word

Comment: @ChuckFulminata, sets _can_ store strings. If you pass a string as the parameter to set, it will of course treat it as a sequence of characters. try `set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])`

Comment: I wouldn't bother with `set.union`, that will create a bunch of increasingly larger sets and throw them away: `words = set(word for line in open('book.txt', 'r') for word in line.split())`.

Comment: I've also noticed on SO that quite a few people prefer `itertools.chain.from_iterable` rather than a comprehension with two `for` clauses. So although I wouldn't write it myself, an alternative is `set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in open('book.txt', 'r')))`.

Comment: If we're going to be maximally efficient, wouldn't we want to read character by character and tokenize as we consume the stream rather than reading an entire line in to memory, then tokenizing it?  Plus, there's no guarantee that the file is chunked up nicely with line breaks; worst case, it could contain no line breaks at all.

Comment: @SilasRay: I can't speak for others, but I am going for "reasonably efficient under what appear to be reasonable assumptions" rather than "maximally efficient in the worst case".

Comment: @SteveJessop: I am yet to warm up to `itertools.chain.from_iterable` for this sort of thing. Maybe I should try using it in anger.

Comment: @SilasRay, yes, it's possible the lines are very long. Luckily it doesn't happen very often in real life, so it's rarely worth mentioning unless someone specifies it in the question.

Comment: @gnibbler Long lines relative to the length of the file.  Like, say, a file containing a short story (where line breaks only occur between paragraphs), an email, un-beautified JSON... It doesn't happen in the aggregate often, but it could be quite common in certain problem domains.

Answer (score 2):

A `set` is a hash table while a `list` is an array.  `set` membership tests are O(1) while list membership tests are O(n).  If anything, you should be filtering the `list` using a `set`, not filtering a `set` using a `list`.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken in your meaning, I am filtering a list with a set

Comment: @ChuckFulminata No, you are doing the opposite. You are doing all the filtering when building the `list` and afterwards you are using it to create a set => you are filtering a `set` using a `list`.

Comment: You are using a membership test on a list to filter the data, then converting it to a set.  If you want to end up with a set, you don't need a list at all, but if you mean to have a list (for example, because order matters) of uniques, doing the membership filter on a set would be more efficient in many cases.  Of course, it's still YMMV, since depending upon duplicate frequency and input length, inserts in to both might outweigh any membership testing costs.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm with `word in list` is an expensive operation. Why? Because, to see if an item is in the list, you have to check *every item in the list*. Every time. It's a [Shlemiel the painter algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html). Every lookup is O(n), and you do it n times. There's no startup cost, but it gets expensive very quickly. And you end up looking at each item way more than one time - on average, len(list)/2 times.

Looking to see if things are in the set, is (usually) MUCH cheaper. Items are hashed, so you calculate the hash, look there, and if it's not there, it's not in the set - O(1). You do have to create the set the first time, so you'll look at every item once. Then you look at each item one more time to see if it's already in your set. Still overall O(n).

So, doing `list(set(mylist))` is definitely preferable to your first solution.

Comment: It's not exponential.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! `word in list` is O(n), which makes the first algorithm exponential.

Comment: The first algorithm isn't exponential either, it's `O(n^2)`.

Comment: that's what i get for trying to be clever :) thanks to both of you for correcting me...

Answer (score 1):

It's worth testing to find out; but I frequently use comprehensions to filter my lists, and I find that works well; particularly if the code is experimental and subject to change.

```
l = list( open( 'book.txt', 'r').read().split() )
unique_l = list(set( l ))
# maybe something else:
good_l = [ word for word in l if not word in naughty_words ]
```

I have heard that this helps with efficiency; but as I said, a test tells more.

Comment: Why prefer the list comprehension to a generator or set comprehension?

Comment: You can use set comprehension like this `{word for word in open('book.txt','r').read().split()}`. No need to create a list at all :)

Comment: Yes, rushed in my answer, I edited.  @Steve, I have nothing against generators.  I still have to maintain compatibility across many versions of python so I don't use dictionary comprehensions; usually use dict() around a generator or list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

@NPE's answer doesn't close the file explicitly. It's better to use a context manager

```
with open('book.txt','r') as fin:
    words = set(fin.read().split())
```

For normal text files this is probably adequate. If it's an entire DNA sequence for example you probably don't want to read the entire file into memory at once.

Comment: `'r'` is the default mode :) and wait, you are calling `read` on a `set` object?

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Sorry, got distracted for a moment. @thefourtheye, some people prefer to be explicit about the mode, especially since Python3